# Limiting results with the fuel sdk

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, fuel-sdk

I am using the PHP Fuel SDK to grab a bunch of send id results. I'm using a filter like this.

```
$sendFilter = array('Property' => 'ID','SimpleOperator' => 'IN','Value' => $sendIDs);
```

How can I limit the result. $sendIDs array may have hundreds in it, but I only want the latest 30 or so. I can use date ranges, but I won't know when the last sends happened.

Edit: I just now thought about grabbing the most recent 30 from the $sendIDs array, but still curious to know if there is a way to limit the actual API call result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't think of this first, but a simple solution that does not require sending a limit.

```
$sendIDs = array_slice($sendIDs, -30, 30);
```

This will send only the most recent 30 to the filter.